# How to add datepicker in magento 2 frontend form

Tags: magento2, datepicker

I want to add a datepicker in magento 2 payment method form . Anybody have an idea how to add date picker through knockout js and data-bind in html page please help me on this ?

Answer (score 21):

you can use the magento 2 datepicker.
It use the jquery_ui datepicker.

Try this in your phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/calendar"
], function($){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       prevText: '&#x3c;zurück', prevStatus: '',
        prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', prevJumpStatus: '',
        nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;', nextStatus: '',
        nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', nextJumpStatus: '',
        monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni',
        'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mär','Apr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
        dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
        dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
      showMonthAfterYear: false,
      dateFormat:'d.m.yy'
    } 
  );
});
</script>
```

Example with form:

```
<div class="field col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="response-field-date">
        <div class="subtemplate-wrapper">
            <label for="" style="" class="">Terminwunsch</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-box col-sm-12">
                    <input name="terminwunsch" id="datepicker" title="Terminwunsch" value="" type="text">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    require([
                        "jquery",
                        "mage/calendar"
                        ], function($){
                          $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                               prevText: '&#x3c;zurück', prevStatus: '',
                                prevJumpText: '&#x3c;&#x3c;', prevJumpStatus: '',
                                nextText: 'Vor&#x3e;', nextStatus: '',
                                nextJumpText: '&#x3e;&#x3e;', nextJumpStatus: '',
                                monthNames: ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni',
                                'Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
                                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mär','Apr','Mai','Jun',
                                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez'],
                                dayNames: ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag'],
                                dayNamesShort: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
                                dayNamesMin: ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
                              showMonthAfterYear: false,
                              dateFormat:'d.m.yy'
                            } 
                          );
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: already added the above script but not working .

Comment: Did you activate the datepicker in the backend?

Comment: How to activate the datepicker in backend ?

Comment: Go to the backend, click on shops->configuration->catalog->catalog and down to the last section with "custom date..." ore something like this.

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Still works in 2019

Answer (score 3):

Yet another approach:

```
<div class="field date">
    <label for="date" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <?=
                $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date')
                    ->setData([
                        'name' => 'date',
                        'id' => 'date',
                        'value' => $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getDate()),
                        'date_format' => 'dd-MM-y',
                        'image' => $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::calendar.png'),
                        'years_range' => '-120y:c+nn',
                        'max_date' => '-1d',
                        'change_month' => 'true',
                        'change_year' => 'true',
                        'show_on' => 'both',
                        'first_day' => 1
                    ])
                    ->toHtml()
            ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's very useful, do you know if there is a block for all the other input types (text, textarea, select, etc)? It would a lot better than write the html from scratch

Answer (score 2):

In my Magento 2 template file, I added following code to display a date picker field :

```
<?php 
  echo $block->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob')
             ->toHtml() 
?>
```

Comment: Is is possible to add time

Comment: You should check one of these links : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252734/50635 - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46854/50635 - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193334/50635

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to solve your point:

```
 <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" class="datepicker"> <script> require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){         $("#datepicker").datepicker({           dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',           changeMonth: true,          changeYear: true,          yearRange: '2010:2025',          showMonthAfterYear: false,        }) }); </script>
```