# How to use frontend calendar localization?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, localisation, calendar

I'm becoming crazy with the frontend translation of the `mage/calendar` widget in Magento 2.
Does somebody know how to localize it?

I have a calendar that's showing up on the front (from a bought module that has a specific class for the calendar) but I've not been able to display the months/day in French. 
This specific frontend calendar is a very simple inheritance of the mage/calendar widget so I don't think that's a problem.

As the calendar widget is based on the jQuery UI calendar, I've tried to translate it as it is recommended in the [jquery UI doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but it does not seem to work.

I've seen in the backend, on the product edit page, that there's a translated calendar for the date attributes 'set the product as new from' and it looks like the options of the knockout input are the following:

```
dateFormat:"dd/MM/y"
showsTime:true
storeLocale:"fr_FR"
timeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

But initializing my calendar with the following options on the front does not change anything, my calendar stay in English :

```
initCalendar: function() {
    $(this.element).calendar({
        dateFormat: this.options.calendarDateFormat,
        minDate: this.minDate.toDate(),
        setDate: 0,
        showOn: 'button',
        storeLocale: "fr_FR"
    });
},
```

I think I'm missing a little something but I don't know what and I have not been able to find any clear answer on the Internet... If anybody has already solved this issue, I would be really happy to read your answer

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea how to solve this for the kind of implementation of the calendar I have in this module but I replaced the calendar initialized with some `data-mage-init` and specific object by [this simple implementation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146448/how-to-add-datepicker-in-magento-2-frontend-form) and it works fine...