# Magento 2 DateTime picker - Limit time selection range

Tags: magento2, datepicker, calendar

I am using a `datetimepicker` on my frontend form with below code. I want to limit time selection between range `09:00` to `17:30`

```
<input name="datetime_field" id="datetime_field" readonly title="Appointment Date" value="" placeholder="Date & Time" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

script for `datetimepicker`,

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {
        var minHour = 9;
        var maxHour = 17;
        $("#datetime_field").calendar({
            showsTime: true,
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            buttonText: "<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
            hourMin: minHour,
            hourMax: maxHour,
        });
    });
</script>
```

I used `minHour` and `maxHour` which limits time selection between `09:00` to `17:59`. How can I limit it to `17:30`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timepicker uses `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js`. In the latest version 1.6.3, which can be found [here](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon), you can specify `minTime` and `maxTime` settings.

You can override Magento's default js file (if it's not the latest) with the latest version and your code would be like:

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {        
        $("#datetime_field").calendar({
            showsTime: true,
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            buttonText: "<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
            minTime: '9:00 am',
            maxTime: '5:30 pm'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have added a datetime picker when i select today date and time save it it show random date ( 2191-04-05 00:00:00)  With 00 in time field in DB

Answer (score 0):

-> it will show am/pm 12 hour format and min and max hour

```
<input type="text" name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" value="" class="datetimepicker">
    <script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/calendar'
    ], function($){
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            showsTime: true,
            showHour: true,
            showMinute: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy,',
            hourMin: 9,
            hourMax: 17,
            stepMinute : 5,
        });
    });
    </script>
```