# Datepicker not working on registration form in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, datepicker, customer-registration

This is my code for DOB on the registration form and its not working. It just displays a text box and not date picker.

```
 <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?php echo $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Can you please share the error or the output of the code `$block->getFormData()->getDob()` .

Comment: @KKR it displays nothing, not the log displays any error

Comment: @RkRathod Yes it is enable and marked as optional

Comment: @RkRathod see it is displayed as a text box https://prnt.sc/orxrpo

Comment: check your custom code or custom module because in fresh setup  work completely

Comment: refer this link if it's relevant to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146448/how-to-add-datepicker-in-magento-2-frontend-form**